# How to stop Fedora 22 from eating up my traffic

Tags: fedora

I have installed Fedora 22 in VMWare 12. I noticed that whenever I start the virtual machine and log into Fedora, it starts eating up my traffic as monitored via Windows. I have no clue which process or daemon does this. I suspect there is some auto update or something Fedora that I should disable. So, I tried the following:

```
[root@localhost mehdi]# gsettings set  org.gnome.software download-updates false
[root@localhost mehdi]# gsettings get  org.gnome.software download-updates
```

But,the second command returns true! And it seems to have no effect on the usage of bandwidth. I had to manually click on the top-right corner of the Gnome screen to disconnect network but other times I forget it and incur costs.

Comment: You can use `iftop` from within Fedora to at least tell you what host it's connecting to (probably after installing it). That may provide some clues.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to stop Fedora from automatically connecting to the network, by changing network interface settings and unchecking `Connect automatically` in the settings, as shown in the following screenshots.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Surely not the best solution but this way at least the system does not automatically start to connect and secretly steal the bandwidth when the system boots up.